# Having a problem with ArrayList Java Import

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I run my coding and it shows this error,

`ArrayList.java:2: error: ArrayList is already defined in this compilation unit import java.util.ArrayList;` 
when im trying to import arraylist to the class. I tried to remove it but it cannot read the add() method from my coding,

`

```
ArrayList.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
         itemList1.add(x);
                  ^
  symbol:   method add(Item)
  location: variable itemList1 of type ArrayList
```

`
I tried to research everything i could but still could not find the answers. Here is my coding,

`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayList
{
   public static void main(String[]args)
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      
      ArrayList itemList1 = new ArrayList();
      ArrayList itemList2 = new ArrayList();
      
      String itemName, itemId, factoryProduce;
      double itemPrice;
      int itemQuantity;
      
      for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
      {
         itemName = input.next();
         itemId = input.next();
         itemPrice = input.nextDouble();
         itemQuantity = input.nextInt();
         factoryProduce = input.next();         
         
         Item x = new Item(itemName, itemId, itemPrice, itemQuantity, factoryProduce);
      
         itemList1.add(x);
      }
            
      int count = 0;
      
      Object n; //object that does not refer to any class
      
      for(int i=0; i<itemList1.size(); i++) //casting
      {
         n = itemList1.get(i);
         
         Item nan = (Item) n;
         
         if(nn.getFactoryProduce().equalsIgnoreCase("QuickService"))
         {
            itemList2.add(nn);
            itemList1.remove(i);
            
            count++;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

`

I tried a lot of times with the arraylist object declaration and include the import but still got the same error.

Comment: Don't call your own class `ArrayList`. That is just asking for trouble. Because you called your own class `ArrayList` the compiler thinks you are referring to your own class whenever you write `ArrayList` in your code.

Comment: You could get around that problem by always using the full qualified name of `java.util.ArrayList` to distinguish it from your own `ArrayList` class. But really, the real solution is to simply not call your own java classes the same as standard Java classes.